# PHP monthly Invoice/billing statement

Tags: php, sql, paypal

I would like to create a billing system. This system should show on their profile a 20$ reoccurring payment for the services they suscribed at.

If they add a new one to their account, the statement have to update the new amount (for example 30$) depending on the service they selected.

I've already created a cart in PHP, I know how to add items to my cart and do a  checkout. I'm just a bit confused about how I would make this unique for every individual user.
Add to cart.

```html
<?php
session_start();

// Get the product id
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";

 //Check if the cart array was created
 //If it isn't, create the cart array
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
 $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}

//Check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart_items'])){
 // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
 header('Location: products.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}

//If not, then add the item to the array
else{
 $_SESSION['cart_items'][$id]=$name;
 
 //Redirects to product list
 header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
?>
```

Cart page:

```html
<?php
session_start();

$page_title="Cart";
include 'layout_head.php';

$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";

if($action=='removed'){
 echo "<div class='Wow danger'>";
  echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> was removed from your cart.";
 echo "</div>";
}

else if($action=='quantity_updated'){
 echo "<div class='Wow danger'>";
  echo "<strong>{$name}</strong> quantity was updated.";
 echo "</div>";
}

if(count($_SESSION['cart_items'])>0){

 //Gets the Product Id's
 $ids = "";
 foreach($_SESSION['cart_items'] as $id=>$value){
  $ids = $ids . $id . ",";
 }
 
 //Removes the comma
 $ids = rtrim($ids, ',');
 
 //Starts Table
 echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
    
        // Table heading
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th class='textAlignLeft'>Product Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Price (USD)</th>";
   echo "<th>Action</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
  
  $query = "SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id IN ({$ids}) ORDER BY name";
  
  $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
  $stmt->execute();

  $total_price=0;
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
   
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
    echo "<td>&#36;{$price}</td>";
    echo "<td>";
     echo "<a href='remove_from_cart.php?id={$id}&name={$name}' class='btn btn-danger'>";
      echo "<span class='shopping cart-remove'></span> Remove from cart";
     echo "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
   
   $total_price+=$price;
  }
  
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><b>Total</b></td>";
    echo "<td>&#36;{$total_price}</td>";
    echo "<td>";
     echo "<a href='#' class='success'>";
      echo "<span class='shopping-cart'></span> Checkout";
     echo "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
  
 echo "</table>";
}

else{
 echo "<div class='Wow danger'>";
  echo "<strong>No products found</strong> in your cart!";
 echo "</div>";
}

include 'layout_foot.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the real problem here? It's nothing really sophisticated than what you've did before. You'll have some tables like:

- offers (id, price, name)
- users (id, name)
- subscriptions (id, offer_id, user_id, startDate)

Just add a new row in the subscription for each services bought by a user and calcul the sum of his invoice. Then just run a CRON each day for example and send email depending on if the user need to pay his subscription, or not.

Comment: But how would I do this in PHP?

Comment: Nothing hard in it, are you sure to understand PHP? Maybe you should try to read again a tutorial

Comment: I just want a bit of a hint, Like I said, I am new to this.